# SSH broken in for user with no shell

Tags: ssh, security, authentication

I think that my Ubuntu box was broken in and the hacker tried to spam email (through port 25) with my computer.

Part of `/var/log/auth.log` is extracted as below (I changed the actual user into `myuser` and some external IP address into `1.2.3.x`):

```
Feb 20 06:07:12 ubuntu systemd-logind[954]: New session 77 of user myuser.
Feb 20 06:08:22 ubuntu sshd[21251]: error: connect_to 1.2.3.4 port 25: failed.
Feb 20 06:08:22 ubuntu sshd[21251]: error: connect_to 1.2.3.5 port 25: failed.
Feb 20 06:08:22 ubuntu sshd[21251]: error: connect_to 1.2.3.5 port 25: failed.
Feb 20 06:08:22 ubuntu sshd[21251]: error: connect_to 1.2.3.6 port 25: failed.
...(thousands of similar lines follows)...
```

Since the error message was generated by `sshd`, I suppose that the hacker gained access through logging in SSH as `myuser`.  Its respective record in `/etc/passwd` is as below:

```
myuser:x:1003:1004:myuser:/home/myuser:/bin/false
```

I suppose the hacker should not have been able to log in as the shell for `myuser` is `/bin/false`, i.e. it should be kicked out immediately even if he can log in.  I cannot login `myuser` through PuTTY as well.  The login record for my own login is something like:

```
Feb 22 10:26:58 ubuntu sshd[3653]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myuser by (uid=0)
Feb 22 10:26:58 ubuntu systemd-logind[734]: New session 2 of user myuser.
Feb 22 10:26:58 ubuntu sshd[3653]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myuser
```

So, obviously there is something wrong with my settings, and/or `/bin/false` is not working in `/etc/passwd` file.  What's wrong with my current setting, and how should I fix the loophole?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article in commandline.ninja about /bin/false, /sbin/nologin and SSH](https://web.archive.org/web/20190320192153/http://commandline.ninja/2012/05/06/binfalse-sbinnologin-and-ssh/) seems to answer your question.

##Executive Summary

A hacker can bypass the protection of using `/bin/false` as the shell for that user using **port forwarding** via the `ssh` command like:

```
[user@panel~] ssh -N testacct@linuxserver.cconn.info -L 2525:127.0.0.1:25
```

##Temp fixes

###Disable port forwarding

> The simplest and most drastic, if possible in your scenario, is to
> simply disable TCP port forwarding in your `sshd` configuration file
> (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on many systems):

> ```
> AllowAgentForwarding no
> AllowTcpForwarding no
> X11Forwarding no
> ```

###Block user account/password

- Edit `/etc/shadow` and set the user’s password to be `*`
- Confirm that no SSH key for this user exists in your system.

[Shadow password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd)
having `*` as the encrypted password in `/etc/shadow` means that the account is locked, the user will be unable to log-in via password authentication **but other methods (e.g. SSH key) may be still allowed**.

---

More info can be found at [commandline.ninja about /bin/false, /sbin/nologin and SSH](https://web.archive.org/web/20190320192153/http://commandline.ninja/2012/05/06/binfalse-sbinnologin-and-ssh/).

Comment: I don't think you have to include the entire text of that blog post here. You have provided the summary and the useful parts, is there any value to including it all here?

Comment: @muru - thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks - finally I applied the solution mentioned in the blog by configuring `AllowUser` / `AllowGroup` directives in the sshd configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and restrict login for users that requires SSH.  I did not take the temp fixed suggested as they limited the port forward capability that I needed, and I cannot block the user as it provides some services.

Comment: @KennethL - I'm happy that my answer helped. Can you please explain, why can't you block the user (e.g. using `*` in /etc/shadow, etc)? Does the services provided by the user required a password for this user? Is there any legitimate scenario which include entering a password for a user with `/bin/false` as a shell?

Comment: I created the user which kept some files that need to be accessible by other Windows machine on the same network.  And there are other system users that may be posing a threat too.  Since there are only limited user that requires SSH access, it seems safer to block all SSH access other than those legitimate users with `AllowUser` directive.

Comment: Also, compare the relevant binaries (certainly all parts of the ssh package, relevant PAM libraries and all the dependencies) against some from a known OK install at the same patch level. If this sounds like something you don't feel confident to do, and cannot find out HOW somebody gained access to the myuser account, consider the whole system suspect and best off the open internet!

Comment: @rackandboneman Thanks for your additional comments but it's too advanced and I have totally no idea what's that about. Could you introduce me with some tutorial or google keywords so that I can better grasp an idea what's that about?

Comment: What I wanted to say: If someone busted the lock on your door and you don't know how he busted the lock, assume he left your door with a busted lock (that allows him and/or others to still come in freely even if you take his stolen keys away). If you can't replace the lock and be certain you replaced it, take extra measures or move house (put machine behind firewall and/or reinstall).